Analytical Approaches to Solving a Fredholm Integral Equation of the First Kind Over a Simplex
I am working with a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind, defined over a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The simplex $A$ is described as follows:
\begin{equation*}
A = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \leq 1, y_i \geq 0 \text{ for all } i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \}
\end{equation*}
The vertices of the simplex, $ \{v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_n\} $, are standard unit vectors including the origin.
Given the equation:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{A \setminus V} \frac{\theta - X}{\|\theta - X\|} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \|\theta - X\|^2\right) g(\theta) \, d\theta = -\sum_{\theta \in V} \frac{\theta - X}{\|\theta - X\|} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \|\theta - X\|^2\right)
\end{equation*}
where $X$ is a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $V$ is the set of vertices, and $ \|\cdot\| $ denotes the Euclidean norm. The kernel $ K(\theta, X) $ and the function $ f(X) $ are defined as:
\begin{equation*}
K(\theta, X) = \frac{\theta - X}{\|\theta - X\|} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \|\theta - X\|^2\right)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
f(X) = -\sum_{\theta \in V} K(\theta, X)
\end{equation*}
This equation poses a challenge due to its form as a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind. I am seeking insights on whether there are analytical methods to solve for $ g(\theta)$. Additionally, is there a way to reformulate this problem as a Fredholm integral equation of the second kind, which might be easier to solve analytically?
